# Android get device screen height and width for all resolutions

Tags: android, screen

i have used below code but some resolutions like Nexus 5(lolipop - 5.0), device height and width are not returning actual values.
    `DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    width = metrics.heightPixels;
    height = metrics.widthPixels;`

Comment: Tried `getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;`? Means `DisplayMetrics metrics = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();`

Answer (score 4):

I use the following utility functions:

```
private static int sScreenWidthDP = -1;
private static int sScreenWidth = -1;
private static int sScreenHeight = -1;

public static int getScreenHeight(Context context) {
        if (sScreenHeight == -1) {
            Display display = ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            sScreenHeight = size.y;
        }
        return sScreenHeight;
    }

    public static int getScreenHeightInDp(Context context) {
        if (sScreenHeight == -1) {
            Display display = ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            sScreenHeight = size.y;
        }
        return pixelsToDp(context, sScreenHeight);
    }

    public static int getScreenWidthInDp(Context context) {
        if (sScreenWidthDP == -1) {
            Display display = ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            sScreenWidthDP = pixelsToDp(context, size.x);
        }
        return sScreenWidthDP;
    }
public static int getScreenWidth(Context context) {
        if (sScreenWidth == -1) {
            Display display = ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            sScreenWidth = size.x;
        }

        return sScreenWidth;
    }
public static float dpToPixels(Context context, int dp) {
        return TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }

    public static int pixelsToDp(Context context, float pixels) {
        float density = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
        return Math.round(pixels / (density / 160f));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code to get width or height

```
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);

    int height = size.y;
    int width = size.x;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following way, it enables you to get the real size of the device:

```
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getRealSize(size);
    int width = size.x;
    int height = size.y;
```